# Tweaking style/attributes of existing Graphics objects in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

One of Mathematica's strengths is its consistent underlying representation of objects.  Thus, to change attributes of a plot without redoing the computation used to generate it, I could do something like

```
Replace[myplot, {Graphics[x_List, y_List] :> 
 Graphics[x,Flatten[{y, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Helvetica, FontSize -> 20}}]]}]
```

Unfortunately, every time I want to use this approach to modify a plot in order to change the style/color of lines, points, fonts, etc. I have to figure out what the appropriate replacement rule is by trial and error, which negates any efficiency gained by not having to recompute the plotted data.  Here's another example:

```
myplot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[None]}, {Green, Dashing[None]}}]

myplot /. { {x___, PatternSequence[Red, Dashing[_]], y___}
              -> {x, Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny], y},
            {x___, Green, y___}
              -> {x, Thickness[Large], Red, y} }
```

This gets the job done (changes line color/dashing/thickness), but seems voodoo-ish.

Is there any documentation (guides or tutorials) -- short of poring over the exact specifications for Graphics objects and primitives -- that could guide me in constructing the appropriate replacements?..  If not, are there better ways of tweaking the appearance of plots without recomputing (other than saving data in a variable and using ListPlot)?

Comment: Probably the most sound approach is to extract data points from Graphics, use those data points in the interpolating function and re-plot with changed styles.

Comment: Leo, can you provide a few examples of what want to do?  There are so many ways one could manipulate graphics it is hard to know how to respond.

Comment: The most common adjustments I want to make are: (a) to change the attributes of lines or points (e.g. thickness/color/dashing pattern) and (b) adjust the style of ticks/frames/axes/labels

Comment: I made an edit to your post in an attempt to improve readability.  In this instance `Show` was extraneous.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Here's something that may be of interest... Create a basic example plot, click to select the output, then right click and choose 'drawing tools'. You can then click on an individual curve, say, and change it's color, dashing, etc. When you're done tinkering, click on the output cell bracket, then right click and 'convert to' InputForm. This gives you access to exact data points and options @Sasha suggested. While I haven't used my own suggestion much, it may make it easier to build up programmatically annotated (text) plots in the future. Custom mouse-overs might be another use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I await more examples of your desired manipulations, but for now I'll point out that it may be possible to do a class of them without replacements at all.  Forced to merely guess at what you want, one interpretation follows.

```
myplot = Plot[{Sin[x], Csc[x]}, {x, 1, 10}];

Replace[myplot, {Graphics[x_List, y_List] :> 
   Graphics[x, 
    Flatten[{y, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20}}]]}]

Show[myplot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20}]
```

As you can see, in this case `Replace` is not needed.

---

Addressing your updated question, there are two different categories of graphical objects in a `Plot` output.

1. The plotted lines of the functions (`Sin[x]`, `Cos[x]`) and their styles are "hard coded" into `Line` objects, which `Graphics` can understand.
2. Auxiliary settings such as `Axes -> True`, `PlotLabel -> "Sine Cosecant Plot"` and `AxesStyle -> Orange` are understood by `Graphics` directly, without conversion, and therefore remain within the `myplot` object.

The second kind of settings can be easily changed after the fact because they are soft settings.

The first kind much be processed in some way.  This is complicated by the fact that different `*Plot` functions output different patterns of `Graphics` and `Plot` itself may give different patterns of output depending on the input it is given.

I am not aware of any global way to restyle all plot types, and if you do such restyling often, it probably makes more sense to retain the data that is required and simply regenerate the graphic with Plot.  Nevertheless, for basic uses, your method can be improved.  Each function plotted creates a `Line` object, in the given order.  Therefore, you can use something like this to completely restyle a plot:

```
myplot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[None]}, {Green, Dashing[None]}}]

newstyles = Directive @@@
   {{Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]},
    {Thickness[Large], Red}};
```

```
i = 1;
MapAt[# /. {__, l : Line[__]} :> {newstyles[[i++]], l} &, myplot, {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Please note the part in bold-italic in the last line of code above.  This is the part specification for the location of the `Line` objects within `myplot`, and it may change.  Usually this will work as is, but if you find that you must change this often, a function to detect its position should be possible (ask if needed).

---

#### Graphics Inspector

telefunkenvf14's comment reminded me that I was negligent to not mention the Graphics Inspector.

While I personally tend to avoid extensive after-Plot restyling, because I like to keep everything on one place (the `Plot` command), and I prefer to make what changes I do with code, so that there is a record of my settings without having to dig into the `Graphics` object, the Graphics Inspector is directly applicable.

- Double click the plot.  The border should change from orange to thick gray.
- Single click one of the plot lines. (the pointed should change when you hover over an element)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to open the Graphics Inspector.
- Make the changes you desire, and close the Graphics Inspector.

You can now copy and paste the entire graphic, or directly assign it to a symbol: `p = <graphic>`

Also, see:  http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/howtoeditmathematicagraphics/

Comment: Ok, I suspected I was doing something silly with my replacements :)  From some more experimentation, it seems that `Style[]` is a good way of changing attributes related to frames/axes/ticks/labels.  It could also be used to add additional graphical elements e.g. through `Epilog[]`.  Is there anything similar to adjust line type/color without resorting to the voodoo in my example (just added to original question)?

Comment: Graphics inspector? Not in version 8 at least. Ctrl-g doesn't work for me either. Perhaps you mean the Drawing tools palette? It allows you to edit various aspects of drawing styles. It's ctrl-D on my machine.

Comment: @Sjoerd I guess they removed it, or combined it with Drawing Tools.  On v7 it is quite clearly in the Graphics menu, and the title of the window that appears is 2D Graphics Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find it useful to replace the entire rule/option, rather than just the RHS of the rule. For instance, something like this, based on your example:

```
myplot /. (PlotStyle -> x__) -> (PlotStyle -> myRestyle[x]);
```

I also like that this avoids the problem of appending duplicates of the option.

This is handy for restyling other objects, such as:

```
styledText /. (FontSize->x_) -> (FontSize->2x)
```