# Capital letters for named patterns

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols, names

In *Mathematica* built-in Symbols start with capital letters.  Therefore it is accepted practice to not start user created symbol names with capital letters.

How far should this restriction be extended to other aspects of syntax?  Does good practice demand that a capital letter not be used for a named pattern in a `SetDelayed` or `RuleDelayed` expression (where such names are localized)?

I think that capitals expand the namespace in a useful way and visually distinguish between lowercase L and 1, for example.  They also allow arguments to be named in a textbook fashion.

If new symbols are introduced in future versions, the named patters should supersede these, and existing code should not break.

A con is ambiguity if existing names such as `N` and `D` are used, but I feel that both the context of use and FrontEnd syntax highlighting mitigate this.

Comment: +1 But 1 think 1owercase L is easy to distinguish from 1 if your names are descriptive enough. Besides, the namespace expansion usage should be considered with care: naming a symbo1 myHome and another MyHome is a c1assica1 bug stew recipe  ...

Comment: @belisarius Since I have a fondness for terse coding, most of my pattern names are a single character, therefore `l` and `1` are quite similar.  Likewise, it is doubtful I would confuse the symbols in `f[A_, a_] := ... `.  Used globally I agree with you, and I make my global names more verbose, but in this specific case I am wondering if I may change my practice.

Comment: On reflection "most" is not accurate, but many are single letters, especially in short, well encapsulated replacement rules.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644801/tweaking-style-attributes-of-existing-graphics-objects-in-mathematica/5645482#5645482); I would like to change `l : Line[__]` to `L_Line` in that code.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a better font than the default Courier that mma uses to better distinguish `l` and `1` :)

Comment: @yoda http://content.altfonts.com/img/B/B/BB-Monkey0.png :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an accepted practice that I do not accept!

I am referring to packages, for personal or 3rd party use.
In general I want my finished work to be as indistinguishable as possible from the ideal (WRI) quality,look and feel. 
This includes long descriptive names for my commands, with all the capitalization conventions used by WRI.

Of course my packages are - at the moment - nowhere near WRI quality, but at least I am trying to integrate them as best as I can with standard MMA functionality. And this includes having capitalized commands.

During development, syntax highlighting alerts me of possible conflicts with standard MMA functions, so I can take appropriate actions.
Of course my commands and packages may conflict with future releases of MMA, but nothing lasts forever and if a future MMA command is similar in name and functionality to one of mine, I will simply switch to the standard function with minimal or no change in naming.

Besides this, I find visually much more appealing to use capital letters to distinguish package commands from more modest temporary variables.
If you want to see some visually opaque/unappealing code, just look at any average Maple code.

Regarding pattern variables, I try to give meaningful, mostly short, pattern names with no capitals, so the user can guess by looking at the Ctrl/Cmd-K template what kind of input is expected in my package commands.

Comment: I'd say it's useful not to use capitalized names during interactive work / notebooks to avoid *accidental* conflicts with either built-ins *or* with package symbols. If package symbols are capitalized that will aid the user in this, not hinder her.  So yes, I also prefer packages to have capitalized symbol names.

Comment: According to Roman Maeder, using capitalized names for public functions in packages *is* an accepted practice. For packages, capitalized names present no problem, since the full (long) name is different, as the contexts are different (``System` `` vs whatever the package's context is), so clashes manifest themselves as instances of shadowing. Avoiding shadowing is a different problem.